# Is there a bash command to get 5th field in output separated by tabs?

Tags: bash, cut

I am writing a bash script to get the size of a file. I have used the following:

```
ls -lah $1 | cut -d \t -f 5
```

---

The `ls -lah $1` outputs something like the following:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 paolosecci  staff   5.2M Apr 16 19:27 file.txt
```

---

I want to pipeline this output and select only the "5.2M"

Comment: `ls` doesn't use tabs in it's output. Why don't you use `du -sb $1`? `du` has a variety of other useful options as well.

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Use `stat` or `find`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it ..

```
ls -lah $1 | awk '{print $5}'
```

Answer (score 1):

See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs.

Instead, use

```
stat -f '%z' "$1"
```